# How to write a menu driven program in java with an if else statement embedded within a switch case

Tags: java

I am trying to write a menu driven program in java language to calculate the cost of attendance for various types of students at this specific university. I am running into problems with my output, when I run my program none of my cases execute upon entering the according letter. If there are any tips in helping fix my output problem I would greatly appreciate it.

```
int cred, sem, cost, tuition;
char choice;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a for a non resident Grad student/n");
    System.out.println("Enter b for a resident Grad student/n");
    System.out.println("Enter c for an international Grad student/n");
    System.out.println("Enter d for a non resident UnderGrad student/n");
    System.out.println("Enter e for a resident UnderGrad student/n");
    System.out.println("Enter f for an international UnderGrad student/n");
    choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
    tuition = sc.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 'a':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            cost = (780 * cred) + (145 * cred);
            break;

        case 'b':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            cost = (510 * cred) + (110 * cred);
            break;

        case 'c':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            cost = (850 * cred) + (155 * cred);
            break;
        case 'd':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            if (cred > 18)
                tuition = (475 * (cred - 18) + 5850);
            else if (cred < 12)
                tuition = (475 * cred);
            else
                tuition = 5850;
        case 'e':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            if (cred > 18)
                tuition = (325 * (cred - 18) + 4000);
            else if (cred < 12)
                tuition = (325 * cred);
            else
                tuition = 4000;
        case 'f':
            System.out.println("Enter number of credits being taken: ");
            cred = sc.nextInt();
            if (cred > 18)
                tuition = (625 * (cred - 18) + 7550);
            else if (cred < 12)
                tuition = (625 * cred);
            else
                tuition = 7550;
    }
}
while (choice != 's');
System.out.println("Cost of attendance= " + tuition);
```

Comment: What is the desired output ? You should mention that in the question and also what are you getting now?

Comment: I want my output to let me type in "a" for instance and then execute case 'a'.... Currently when I run the program the menu shows up on the output but when I type in the letter 'a' for instance, another blank box shows up and nothing is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any output to tell the user to enter a number for tuition. This is confusing because if not specified, after the prompt to choose a letter between a and f, it appears that the program hangs when in reality it's just waiting for the next integer (`tuition = sc.nextInt()`).

This is why no cases execute. You need to **enter an integer value for the tuition**. You currently have

```
choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
tuition = sc.nextInt(); // problem here
```

That said, the choice `s` (stop?) isn't listed among the available options, so a normal user would have difficulty figuring out how to end the program.

Another observation, you are using `println` and terminating each string with `/n`; The newline character is `\n`, perhaps you meant to use that?

Comment: I'm sorry I am pretty new to programming, does that mean that I need to set tuition=0  when I type my declare my variables?

Comment: `sc.nextInt()` reads the next integer from the keyboard, so until you supply an integer from the keyboard, the program will not continue. The value read in from the keyboard will be assigned to the `tuition` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a selection `choice = sc.next().charAt(0);`, but even if a user chooses `s` to exist the program, you still ask for another input `tuition = sc.nextInt();`, and then in a very last line just print what it has been entered `System.out.println("Cost of attendance= " + tuition);`. Because of this, all the previously inputs are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would point out that in some of your cases you are missing a break; causing more than one case to be executed at a time. Also your cost variable is not needed as you can simply update the tuition variable inside of your case statement so any where you have cost = something you can do tuition += something. Like pointed out by others remove your tuition = sc.nextInt() it is not needed because the value of tuition should not be determined by user input.

Also as a side note even if the code inside the block is one line brackets make your code more readable.

Comment: Also initialize tuition to 0 during declaration